# Отключение границ одной ячейки/строки

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Как отключить границы одной отдельной ячейки DataGridViewCell? Вообще требуется отключить горизонтальные границы на одной строке (без разделителей между ячейками), а на остальных строках выше и ниже нужно, чтобы границы остались.

Comment: Вот, например, написал такой код: 
   
DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle style = new                  DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle();
   style.All = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
         
     foreach (DataGridViewCell i in  this.dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells)
            {
                i.AdjustCellBorderStyle(style,style,true,true,false,false);
            }

НЕ РАБОТАЕТ! Какие флаги и что вообще надо сделать, чтобы заработало?

На msdn-е есть примеры с созданием кастомных классов ячеек и строк. Тоже не работает.

Можно пример работающего кода, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно переопределить метод Paint для ячейки. Так работает. Хорошо работает, только если ячейка ReadOnly, а это как раз мой случай.

```
public class DataGridViewCustomCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    protected override void Paint(
                 Graphics graphics,
                 Rectangle clipBounds,
                 Rectangle cellBounds,
                 int rowIndex,
                 DataGridViewElementStates cellState,
                 Object value,
                 Object formattedValue,
                 string errorText,
                 DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
                 DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
                 DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts
  )
    {

      //  base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);

        SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

        graphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, cellBounds);
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Gray, 1); //+ cellBounds.Height
        graphics.DrawLine(myPen, cellBounds.X, cellBounds.Y + cellBounds.Height- 1,
            cellBounds.X + cellBounds.Width, cellBounds.Y + cellBounds.Height -1);
        myBrush.Dispose();
        if (this.FormattedValue is String)
        {
            TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics,
                (string)this.FormattedValue,
                this.DataGridView.Font,
                cellBounds, SystemColors.GrayText);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].AdjustCellBorderStyle(..  .. ... ...   ) - изменяет стиль границ ячейки в соответствии с указанными критериями. Читайте, там их много.

Выяснилось, что все не так просто. Прочитайте http://rsdn.ru/?article/dotnet/DataGridView20.xml. Есть код к статье.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, непонятно, что значит "отключить границы". Вы используете один из контролов .net Framework, его задача отобразить табличные данные в виде таблицы. Если вам нужно конкретная специфика таблицы - наверное, придется создать свой контрол с возможностью скрыть/показать определенные места.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите данную статью (хоть она и не совсем Вам подходит) - http://arxont.blogspot.com/2010/09/c.html. Скорей всего **свойство border** должно присутствовать.
P.S. Если ссылка не открывается, то:

```
private void DGPaint()
    {          
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < dataGridView1.RowCount; j++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value.ToString() == "Bad")
                {
                    //Меняем цвет ячейки
                    dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    //Меняем шрифт ячейки
                    dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Style.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold);                                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Думаю, что разберетесь...